# Relative path to a sound in android

Tags: android, path

I'm trying to make a button that plays a sound the basic way.

I've used the new SoundPool builder and can't seem to find the way to use my sound, how can I find the path to the sound since I can not put a String in my parameters?

My folder "sounds" is located in res and got one sound file called "eau.mp3" . I tried to use the path res/sounds/eau.mp3 but it can't seem to work. Here is the piece of code that interests us :

```
AudioAttributes attributes=new AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA).setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN).build();
                SoundPool soundPool=new SoundPool.Builder().setAudioAttributes(attributes).build();
                soundPool.load(MainActivity.this, PATH  ,1);
```

What am I suppose to remplace Path with?

Answer (score 0):

If you create the custom folder into resource folder then it does not work.You can play this audio from Assets folder & Sd card path.you need to define the id if you want to use any view or data from resource folder.